# How do I pull counts of email sent to a specific smtp address

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I was asked to see if I could pull statistics on the volumne of email, and specifically the size of attachments sent from within my organization to a particular email address.

I work a lot with Exchange Web services but this seems like a more like a powershell through the Exchange shell type of situtation. Does anyone have any pointers on this? I am comfortable with powershell but I am not familiar with the Exchange cmdlets.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this script for a while now and it works great:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/bb94b422-eb9e-4c53-a454-f7da6ddfb5d6